# .htaccess rewrite not working - suspected alphanumeric characters/backrefrences

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I believe I'm after a quite a simple and common rewrite behavior yet after days (yes days) of battling with .htaccess rewrite rules, reading documentation, trying generators and testers etc I'm still no further in getting this rewriting to happen.

The url I want to rewrite is:

```
http://www.mysite.com/products/adagio.php?prod=Adagio%20BankRec
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/bankrec
```

The following does nothing

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^bankrec$ /products/adagio.php?prod=Adagio%20BankRec
```

If I enable encoded slashes: `AllowEncodedSlashes On` it breaks the site. Also if I add `[B]` flag to denote escape backrefrences it breaks the site.

Can anyone please help me? rewrite rules make me feel like the universe is without order. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `%` character otherwise mod_rewrite will try to replace it by `%2`. Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^bankrec/?$ /products/adagio.php?prod=Adagio\%20BankRec [L,NE]
```